# Changing origin point of an object makes it move in a different axis

Tags: c++, opengl, box2d

I've been working with this GameObject(which utilizes Box2D) and Renderer2D class for some time now, and I haven't had any problems. That was till I decided to add the option to rotate an object. All works fine (or that seems to be) with box 2D, but the object when seen on screen moves in the wrong axis, it becomes smaller when moving Up and bigger when moving down (or closer and further away from the camera).

The only three lines I have added to the Renderer2D script are this:

```
    model = math::translate(model, iVec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
    model = math::rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = math::translate(model, iVec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
```

If I just remove those lines everything works fine, but I want the object to rotate so I can't remove them.

This is the whole Rendering Function:

```
void Renderer2D::Render(Texture & texture, iVec2 position, iVec2 size, float rotation, Color color, iVec2 tiling) {
    this->shader.Use();
    iMat4x4 model;

    model = math::translate(model, iVec3(position, 0.0f));

    model = math::translate(model, iVec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
    model = math::rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = math::translate(model, iVec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));

    model = math::scale(model, iVec3(size, 1.0f));

    this->shader.SetMatrix4("model2D", model);
    this->shader.SetVector3f("spriteColor", iVec3(color.r, color.g, color.b));
    this->shader.SetVector2f("tiling", tiling);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.Bind();

    glBindVertexArray(this->QuadVAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I move the GameObject with the Velocity variable of Box2D, like this:

```
float horizontal, vertical;
        if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.A) || Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.D)) {
            if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.A))
                horizontal = -1;
            else if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.D))
                horizontal = +1;
        }
        else horizontal = 0;

        if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.W) || Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.S)) {
            if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.W))
                vertical = -1;
            else if (Input::GetKeyDown(Input::Key.S))
                vertical = +1;
        }
        else vertical = 0;

        Rigidbody2D->Velocity = iVec2(horizontal, vertical) * speed;
```

I really have tried everything and still don't know if it's a Camera problem or a Renderer or a Box2D. Tried altering the far and near values of the view matrix, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the main problem, after printing the matrix on the console I realized that the fourth column was been replaced from x y 0 1 to 0 x 0 y.

Changed the code from this:

```
model = math::translate(model, iVec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
model = math::rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
model = math::translate(model, iVec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
```

to this and it's done!

```
iMat4x4 tempModel;
iMat4x4 tempModel2;


tempModel = math::translate(tempModel, iVec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
model[3].z = model[3].w = 0;
model[3] = model[3] + tempModel[3];

model = math::rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

tempModel2 = math::translate(tempModel2, iVec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
model[3].z = model[3].w = 0;
model[3] = model[3] + tempModel2[3];
```

Still didn't get the rotation I wanted, but at least other functions work.